# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/UserDataHelper

Tags: tomcat7

I have an spring-hibernate web application running on tomcat server version 7.0.25 with jdk 1.6.0_25

I do not know why but even if I did not change anything about my code or server configurations, this morning I have started to get the following exception.

I would be great if you can share your ideas and solutions. Thanks in advance.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/UserDataHelper

 ...

 2012-09-20 15:02:01,344 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] ERROR org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol- 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Cookies
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.<init>(Request.java:131)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.<init>(AbstractProcessor.java:44)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.<init>(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:257)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.<init>(Http11Processor.java:55)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.createProcessor(Http11Protocol.java:161)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.createProcessor(Http11Protocol.java:99)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:549)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

 Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-8" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.release(Http11Protocol.java:136)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.release(Http11Protocol.java:99)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:638)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has gone without doing anything and I do not know how to close or delete this question.